# Python package is corrupted

Tags: software-installation, python, dpkg, dependencies

After apt-get update I'm getting this output:

```
root@pratik--Notebook:/home/pratik# apt-get install python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python is already the newest version (2.7.11-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-mathjax libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libchm1 libjs-mathjax libldb1 libpodofo0.9.3 libtalloc2 libtevent0 libwbclient0 linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
31 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-beautifulsoup (3.2.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-beautifulsoup (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-bs4 (4.4.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-bs4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-chardet:
 python-chardet depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-chardet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-repoze.lru (0.6-6) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-repoze.lru (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-six (1.10.0-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-six (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-routes:
 python-routes depends on python-repoze.lru; however:
  Package python-repoze.lru is not configured yet.
 python-routes depends on python-six; however:
  Package python-six is not configured yet.
 python-routes depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-routes (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-cherrypy3:
 python-cherrypy3 depends on python-routes; however:
  Package python-routes is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-cherrypy3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-cssutils:
 python-cssutils depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-cssutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-dateutil:
 python-dateutil depends on python-six (>= 1.5); however:
  Package python-six is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-dateutil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-dbus (1.2.0-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-django (1.8.7-1ubuntu5.5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-django (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-dnspython (1.12.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dnspython (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-feedparser (5.1.3-3build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-feedparser (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-gi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-html5lib:
 python-html5lib depends on python-six; however:
  Package python-six is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-html5lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-libxml2 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-libxml2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-lxml (3.5.0-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-lxml (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-markdown (2.6.6-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-markdown (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pil:amd64 (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-pygments (2.1+dfsg-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pygments (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-pyparsing (2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyparsing (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-sip (4.17+dfsg-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-sip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyqt5:
 python-pyqt5 depends on sip-api-11.2; however:
  Package sip-api-11.2 is not installed.
  Package python-sip which provides sip-api-11.2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyqt5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-sqlparse (0.1.18-1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-sqlparse (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-utidylib (0.2-9build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-utidylib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-yaml (3.11-3build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-yaml (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-cssselect (0.9.1+git90c72b0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cssselect (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-mechanize (1:0.2.5-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-mechanize (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-tz (2014.10~dfsg1-0ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-tz (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-webob (1.5.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-webob (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-beautifulsoup
 python-bs4
 python-pkg-resources
 python-chardet
 python-repoze.lru
 python-six
 python-routes
 python-cherrypy3
 python-cssutils
 python-dateutil
 python-dbus
 python-django
 python-dnspython
 python-feedparser
 python-gi
 python-html5lib
 python-libxml2
 python-lxml
 python-markdown
 python-pil:amd64
 python-pygments
 python-pyparsing
 python-sip
 python-pyqt5
 python-sqlparse
 python-utidylib
 python-yaml
 python-cssselect
 python-mechanize
 python-tz
 python-webob
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1

 ##
```

Comment: Have you tried removeing the packages assiciated with python and python itself then reinstall? if you have not what does this do?

Comment: Try this commands `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt -f install` and this one `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: i used that command "sudo dpkg --configure -a ". NOthing happend. I am still getting the same output. Actually i tried uninstalling python after that this error happen. Now nothing is to be able to install.

Comment: Do you use sudo apt -f install ? What is output ?

Comment: same output.. As i posted above.

Comment: Please could you leave the root account or environment and use `sudo` from your own environment!

Comment: I did that... nothing happen. Same error

Comment: Please add the outputs of `python --version` and `dpkg -S /usr/bin/pycompile` - it kind of looks like your system is trying to run it with python3 instead of python2

Comment: `python --version`
 --> Python 3.5.2
`dpkg -S /usr/bin/pycompile`
--> python-minimal: /usr/bin/pycompile

Comment: Riiight... so you have somehow (possibly by symlinking, or by installing python 3.5.2 manually from source) made `python3` the default `python` on your system - it needs to be `python2`

Comment: Now i removed python3 from default, by using this command. `update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python3`.   NOw output of this command `python --version` is this `bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try symlinking `python` to `python2`

```bash
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks... I did it previously but nothing happend. Because python2 package was unable to locate in /usr/bin/.... I installed python2 anyhow and after that i did the same as u mentioned above, and it worked pretty well.

Comment: I'm glad it worked